# Receving an email via a Python script

Tags: python, email, outlook

I've written the following script for sending email:

```
to = 'ToAddress@mail.com'
gmail_user = 'FromAddress@mail.com'
gmail_pwd = 'User_password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:testing \n'
print header
msg = header + '\n this is test msg from Python email \n\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
print 'done!'
smtpserver.close()

time.sleep(5)
```

Now i want to receive a mail from outlook express , access and open the mail via a python script. I've tried the codes present for pop and imap lib. But i can't seem to make it work correctly.

Could anyone guide me through this process with any suggestions?

Comment: Using a pop or imap lib is the right track, what problems did you run into?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Outlook... How are you getting these mails into Outlook? You should be doing the same.

Comment: There is no "combination" that "follows" your comment.

Comment: Via the first snippet i sent an email to an email-id which im accessing through outlook.I needed to access the received mail through outlook. I tried the following combination for receiving and it seemed to work -                                                     os.startfile("outlook")                                       outlook = Dispatch('outlook.application')
ns = outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)                        for i in inbox.items:
 print (i.body)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's imaplib to fetch your emails. The PyMOTW series has a [post on imaplib](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/imaplib/) that gives you good examples.

I wrote a script to fetch and filter based on regular expressions in the subject line. It's available [here](https://github.com/nibrahim/openlibrary/blob/master/openlibrary/core/fetchmail.py).

Finally, if you're having problems with imaplib, you should post the relevant tracbacks and other details for more information.

Comment: Thank you for replying , apologies for any improper language or insufficient data provided. Will keep the above in mind. thank you